# symmetric matrix implied by product

Tags: matrices

If $B$ is $n \times p$ full rank, $A$ is $n\times n$ and $C$ is $p\times p$ with $$AB = BC$$ and $A$ is symmetric, is $C$ symmetric?

Comment: What if $B$ is the zero matrix?

Comment: @LouisPan add B is full rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even if we restrict the discussion to $n=p$ and $\det B\ne 0$, in general $A$ symmetric doesn't imply $B^{-1}AB$ symmetric. In point of fact, all diagonalizable matrices are similar to a symmetric matrix, but most of them aren't symmetric.